# passing a pointer to a initialized structure in a function

Tags: c, linux, data-structures

I have this structure like following :

```
typedef struct{
char static_data[10];
int a;
int b;
} my_ds;
```

i have initialized it like following:

```
my_ds * ds = (my_ds *)malloc(sizeof(my_ds));
memmove(my_ds->static_data, buf, len);
ds->a = c;
ds->b = d;
```

and passed it in a function:

```
int my_fun(void ** data);
my_fun((void *)&ds);
```

what happens inside my_fun, the first field, static[10] is initialized correctly but other two values are zero. What am i missing here?

Comment: `char static[10]` ? How did you declare a field called `static` 0.o ?

Comment: sorry for that, corrected it.

Comment: Please show real code that compiles and reproduces the problem.

Comment: real code is too big to show here, i will write a small one which can be compiled and posted here which will reproduce the problem.

Comment: memmove()? You mean memcpy() or strcpy() or maybe even strncpy() !

Answer (score 0):

memmove()? I guess you intended to use memcpy() or strcpy() or maybe even strncpy() !

Also the double ** are (probably) not needed in `my_fun(void **data)` A void pointer can point to anything, including a void pointer. (but that depends on the function definition, which was not shown)

In that case, the ampersand (nor the cast) in `my_fun ( (void**) &ds);` is also not needed. *any* pointer can be cast into a void pointer in C.

```
my_ds * ds;
ds = malloc(sizeof *ds);
if (len >= sizeof my_ds->static_data) len = sizeof my_ds->static_data - 1;
memcpy(my_ds->static_data, buf, len);
my_ds->static_data[len] = 0;
ds->a = c;
ds->b = d;
```

Comment: what's wrong with `memmove()`?  It's just `memcpy()` that knows how to deal with overlapping buffers.

Comment: technically, there is nothing wrong with it. But in this case the buffers cannot overlap, so memmove() is not needed. The len argument is still a potential vector for errors, independent of the function used for copying.

Comment: 1. You're right about the *void*** thing. I should have noticed. I will run your suggestions and post updates. Thank you for commenting